# Updated windows always on top in all workspaces

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, workspaces

I'm running 21.04 and Xorg.  I use multiple workspaces a lot.  There are certain apps whose windows end up at the top of the Alt+Tab list in every workspace whenever certain events occur.  An app that opens a new window on another workspace will do this, for instance.  Telegram will do this every time a new message arrives.  The Immersed agent will do this every time a headset connects or disconnects.  The software update prompt will do this every time it appears.

It's really annoying.  Can I disable this behaviour so that windows **always** only appear in the Alt+Tab list for the workspace they're in?

Edit: To be clear, I already have the setting so that windows only appear on the app switcher for the current workspace set.  The problem is not that the switcher shows all apps on all workspaces, but that apps that try to draw attention to themselves always appear at the start of the switcher list, no matter which workspace they're on, until they get attention.  Then they disappear from the list again.

Comment: I deleted my answer because this issue appears to be different. Perhaps add a little of of your comment to make more clear this is unexpected: mention that you already have the gsetting on `current-workspace-true` and that despite that, some apps open on other workspaces still push themselves in the switcher if they reveal themselves as "urgent"